# How to round a MoneyField in Django

Tags: django

Use django-money to represent a product rate. The Model is defined as follows:

```
class ItemPrice(models.Model):
"""
Item price
"""
rate = MoneyField(_('Unit rate'), max_digits=10, decimal_places=2, default_currency='USD')
```

If I want to have the rounded rate in template, such as USD200 but not USD200.23, how to write the code?

Answer (score 0):

There are a couple of ways to do this.  Firstly, you can modify integers and floats in your view logic, for example:

```
import math

rounded = math.floor(200.23)
print(rounded)
# result is 200
```

Also check out Django's floatformat template tags, which may suit your needs:

```
# for example in your view:

context = { 'value': 34.23234 }

# and in your template:

{{ value|floatformat:"0" }}

# will display 34
```

[Documentation on floatformat tags here.](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.0/ref/templates/builtins/#floatformat)

Note: I do not know what the particular features of the MoneyField are, since I don't think that's part of core Django.  I'm assuming it stores floats.

Comment: MoneyField is a string. I know your solution. Just wonder if there is any simple method.

Comment: The floatformat template tag is about as simple as it gets!  If your goal is to store rounded numbers, you will have to perform the logic between post and save.

Answer (score 0):

I wrote this code.

```
@property
def standard_selling_rate_usd_rounded(self):
    amount = self.standard_selling_rate_usd.amount
    rounded = math.floor(int(amount))
    return Money(rounded, 'USD')
```